# Error running the Orbeon form builder in Tomcat 8.0.14

Tags: orbeon

I got Orbeon 4.7.0.201409270001-PE running on Tomcat 8.0.14 to evaluate its functionalities (I got the 90-day evaluation license) but I'm facing an issue with the form builder.

I can access the builder application but the save functionality does not work; when looking at orbeon.log, I get the following error:

```
    xforms-submit-error - setting body document {body: "
    2014-11-04 09:41:19,693 ERROR XFormsServer  -     <!DOCTYPE html><html><head><title>Apache Tomcat/8.0.14 - Error report</title><style type="text/css">H1 {font-family:Tahoma,Arial,sans-serif;color:w
    hite;background-color:#525D76;font-size:22px;} H2 {font-family:Tahoma,Arial,sans-serif;color:white;background-color:#525D76;font-size:16px;} H3 {font-family:Tahoma,Arial,sans-serif;color:white;back
    ground-color:#525D76;font-size:14px;} BODY {font-family:Tahoma,Arial,sans-serif;color:black;background-color:white;} B {font-family:Tahoma,Arial,sans-serif;color:white;background-color:#525D76;} P
    {font-family:Tahoma,Arial,sans-serif;background:white;color:black;font-size:12px;}A {color : black;}A.name {color : black;}.line {height: 1px; background-color: #525D76; border: none;}</style> </he
    ad><body><h1>HTTP Status 500 - configuration file exist-conf.xml not found or not readable</h1><div class="line"></div><p><b>type</b> Exception report</p><p><b>message</b> <u>configuration file exi
    st-conf.xml not found or not readable</u></p><p><b>description</b> <u>The server encountered an internal error that prevented it from fulfilling this request.</u></p><p><b>exception</b></p><pre>jav
    ax.servlet.ServletException: configuration file exist-conf.xml not found or not readable
    2014-11-04 09:41:19,693 ERROR XFormsServer  -           org.exist.http.servlets.EXistServlet.init(EXistServlet.java:109)
    2014-11-04 09:41:19,693 ERROR XFormsServer  -           org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:506)
    2014-11-04 09:41:19,693 ERROR XFormsServer  -           org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79)
    2014-11-04 09:41:19,693 ERROR XFormsServer  -           org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:610)
    2014-11-04 09:41:19,693 ERROR XFormsServer  -           org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:537)
    2014-11-04 09:41:19,693 ERROR XFormsServer  -           org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1081)
    2014-11-04 09:41:19,693 ERROR XFormsServer  -           org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:658)
    2014-11-04 09:41:19,693 ERROR XFormsServer  -           org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11NioProtocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11NioProtocol.java:222)
    2014-11-04 09:41:19,693 ERROR XFormsServer  -           org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1566)
    2014-11-04 09:41:19,693 ERROR XFormsServer  -           org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1523)
    2014-11-04 09:41:19,693 ERROR XFormsServer  -           java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    2014-11-04 09:41:19,693 ERROR XFormsServer  -           java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    2014-11-04 09:41:19,694 ERROR XFormsServer  -           org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    2014-11-04 09:41:19,694 ERROR XFormsServer  -           java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
    2014-11-04 09:41:19,694 ERROR XFormsServer  -     </pre><p><b>note</b> <u>The full stack trace of the root cause is available in the Apache Tomcat/8.0.14 logs.</u></p><hr class="line"><h3>Apache To
    mcat/8.0.14</h3></body></html>"}
```

I can see exist-conf.xml in webapps/orbeon/WEB-INF, and it seems to be a valid XML file.

Folder webapps/orbeon/WEB-INF/exist-data is also present and the permissions seem to be correct for all its files and folders.

Is there anything else I'm missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The documentation says:

NOTE: Tomcat 8 hasn't been tested yet.

See:
https://github.com/orbeon/orbeon-forms/wiki/Installation-~-Tomcat

I tried using Tomcat 8.0.14 and 4.7.0.201409270001-PE, but I got the same error in Form Builder and Form Runner when I went to the summary pages. I didn't make any configuration changes. It looks like Orbeon doesn't work with Tomcat 8 yet.

I'm using Tomcat 7.0.39 and it seems to work fine.

Comment: We've upgraded tons of apps from Tomcat 7 to 8 without any changes whatsoever, and this is the first one that shows any problems. I should have not incorrectly assumed that there should not be a difference.